# can't retrieve image from firebase using picasso library

Tags: android, firebase, picasso

i am making chat app using picasso library

> https://square.github.io/picasso/ 
>   and i am using circleImageView implementation `'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.1'`

and this is the image cropper i am using

```
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'
```

in user profile image i am able to upload the image in firebae successfully but when i am retrieving the image from firebase the image just dissapears.

these are my dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

this is my code to save image in firebase and using Image Cropper

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == GalleryPick && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null)
        {
            Uri imageUri = data.getData();

            CropImage.activity()
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                    .setAspectRatio(1,1)
                    .start(this);
        }

        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                loadingBar.setTitle("Set profile image");
                loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait, your image is uploading....");
                loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                loadingBar.show();

                Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
                StorageReference filePath = userProfileImageRef.child(currentUserId + ".jpg");
                filePath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task)
                    {
                     if (task.isSuccessful())
                     {
                         Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Image Uploaded Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         final String downloadUrl = task.getResult().getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString();

                         RootRef .child("Users").child(currentUserId).child("image")
                                 .setValue(downloadUrl)
                                 .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                     @Override
                                     public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
                                     {
                                      if (task.isSuccessful())
                                      {
                                          Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Image saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                          loadingBar.dismiss();
                                      }
                                      else
                                      {
                                          String message = task.getException().toString();
                                          Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Error: "+ message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                          loadingBar.dismiss();
                                      }
                                     }
                                 });
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         String message = task.getException().toString();
                         Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Error: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         loadingBar.dismiss();
                     }
                    }
                });
            }
        }

    }
```

Here i am retrieving the image from firebase. but the image and CircleImageView both dissapears. and everything is fine.

```
private void RetrieveUserInfo()
    {
        RootRef.child("Users").child(currentUserId)
                .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                    {
                     if((dataSnapshot.exists()) && (dataSnapshot.hasChild("name") && (dataSnapshot.hasChild("image"))))
                     {
                         String retrieveUserName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                         String retrieveStatus = dataSnapshot.child("Status").getValue().toString();
                         String retrieveProfileImage = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();

                         userName.setText(retrieveUserName);
                         userStatus.setText(retrieveStatus);
                         Picasso.get().load(retrieveProfileImage).into(userProfileImage);
                     }
                     else if ((dataSnapshot.exists()) && (dataSnapshot.hasChild("name")))
                     {
                         String retrieveUserName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                         String retrieveStatus = dataSnapshot.child("Status").getValue().toString();

                         userName.setText(retrieveUserName);
                         userStatus.setText(retrieveStatus);
                     }
                     else
                        {
                            userName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Please update profile info", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError)
                    {

                    }
                });
    }
```

the image cropper is working fine and when i upload the image it also appears in the firebase but in the app it dissapears i have also tried without image cropper but it does not work.

Comment: make sure u declare userProfileImage , sec                          Picasso.get().load("make sure for the retrive data is trully not wrong with debug ").into(userProfileImage); this may help

Comment: i have declared the user `private CircleImageView userProfileImage;` and everything, but it's not working.

Comment: i have fixed it by just changing all the Firebase dependencies to **11.8.0**

Comment: as i told you "make sure for the retrive data is trully not wrong with debug " 
,, anyway happy code and good for you  found it welldone